# Power BI - Syncing slicers

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I would like a monthly report that would update all pages based on a slicer from one page.
On one of the pages I encounter an issue because I only want one of the visuals to be affected of the "master slicer".

[image]

Page with "Master Slicers"

[image]

Page where I only want the top visual to affected, the second I would like to see all months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make the synchronized slicer visible on the target page.
2. Use Format>Edit Interactions to configure the slicer to not filter selected visuals on the target page.
3. Edit the sync slicer to not be visible on the target page.